# Firebase sign up with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

So, I'm having an issue with the code for some reason. I have a Swift app and a sign up view controller that should register users with email in Firebase as a backend (I've upgraded the app to latest Firebase version). I've created some break points to see where it stops working and it turns out that after:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email!, password: password!, completion: {
            user, error in
```

it doesn't execute the whole checking for error or success code, it just moves outside of the scope of the `createUserWithEmail` method. The email and password have values and I see them, but it just continues outside of the scope of the method. I have imported Firebase as a module, it doesn't throw any warning or errors during build time or at compile time

I don't know why this occurs though. Here's the code for the signUp button:

```
@IBAction func signUpTapped(sender: ButtonWhite) {

    let email = emailTextField.text
    let password = passwordTextField.text
    let repeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text

    if email != "" && password != "" && repeatPassword != "" {

        if password == repeatPassword {

            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email!, password: password!, completion: {
                user, error in

                print(user)
                // Error Case 
                if error != nil {

                    if let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code) {
                        switch errorCode {
                        case .ErrorCodeInvalidCredential:
                            showAlert(title: "Invalid Credentials!", msg: "Please, try again.", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
                        case .ErrorCodeNetworkError:
                            showAlert(title: "Network Error!", msg: "An error occurred while attempting to contact the authentication server. Try again", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
                        case .ErrorCodeOperationNotAllowed:
                            showAlert(title: "Bummer!", msg: "The administrator disabled sign in with the specified identity provider", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
                        case .ErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse:
                            showAlert(title: "Oops!", msg: "The email used to attempt a sign up already exists. Please, try again", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
                        case .ErrorCodeInvalidEmail:
                            showAlert(title: "Error", msg: "The email is invalid. Try again.", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
                        case .ErrorCodeTooManyRequests:
                            showAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Too many requests were made to a serve method", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
                        case .ErrrorCodeAccountExistsWithDifferentCredential:
                            showAlert(title: "Error", msg: "User account exists with different credentials than currently submitted. Try again.", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)

                        default:
                            showAlert(title: "Ups!", msg: "An error occur. Please, try again.", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
                        }
                    }

                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()


                } else {

                // Success Case

                    // Create Firebase User
                    let userData = ["provider" : "email", "password": password!]
                    DataService.ds.createFirebaseUser(user!.uid, user: userData)
                    print("firebase user created!")
                    self.loginUser()
                }
            })

        } else {
            showAlert(title: "Password Mismatch", msg: "The passwords you've entered do not match. Please, try again", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
        }
```

Comment: Did you run `FIRApp.configure()`` in your AppDelegate::didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? Also, you don't always enter the completion block on the first attempt. Set a breakpoint inside the completion block and see if you break there.

Comment: Yes! I did. No errors whatsoever

Comment: Try adding this launch option: Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run (on left hand side) -> Arguments passed on launch. Click the plus button and add this: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled

Comment: I did that. Besides this code `2016-06-08 07:38:48.087 Habitory[6134:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` in the console, nothing else changed. It still doesn't run the code inside the method

Comment: Is that all that prints in the console? I get a lot more messages when I run, even without debug enabled. Eg. `2016-06-07 23:50:52.159 [38310:453456] Configuring the default app.`

Comment: No, actually it's a lot more but I've always received those. Here's the entire console: `2016-06-08 08:00:56.924 App[7245:2424605] WARNING: Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
2016-06-08 08:00:57.139 App[7245:2424605] Configuring the default app.
2016-06-08 08:00:57.150 App`

Comment: (cannot compress it to 1 part, here's the rest) : `[7245:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-06-08 08:00:57.155 App[7245:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see somelink)
2016-06-08 08:00:57.173 App[7245:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled`

Comment: @Swifter Hi , I am getting the same problem happening only in release mode.. Did you find a way to write to the DB on sucees case? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is no error, `FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail` will create the user immediately, there would be no need for

```
// Create Firebase User
let userData = ["provider" : "email", "password": password!]
DataService.ds.createFirebaseUser(user!.uid, user: userData)
print("firebase user created!")
self.loginUser()
```

check your firebase console to see if users have been created